# Discord bot will not respond to commands

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots, replit

I am using this Replit demo to create a Discord bot: https://replit.com/@amasad/Discordpy-Music-Bot

I followed the instructions, and my bot is capable of logging in and staying online. The only thing wrong is it won't respond to any of my commands, not even if I add a simple print function.

If it's not in the code, I could have missed something in the Discord bot's permissions, but it can read and write messages as an administrator. I even went into the specific permissions of the server and enabled read/write messages, join voice, etc. Any idea what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have checked out the repl you just mentioned above.

The problem you just mentioned above can occur because of intents, I may or may not be right but since I didn't read your code this is the only thing I can think of at the moment. To fix this what you have to do is, add intents in your client definition. For example:

```py
from discord.ext import commands
import discord

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.all())
```

After this, go to discord developers portal at https://discord.com/developers/applications and open your bot application. Then from the left tab go to `Bot` and you will see a section called `Privileged Gateway Intents` and then turn on the intents.